# How to get the result in below format in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called recipes with following data.

```
page_no title
-----------------
1       pancake
2       pizza
3       pasta
5       cookie
```

`page_no` 0 is always blank, and missing `page_no` are blank, I want output as below, for the blank page NULL values in the result.

```
left_title  right_title
------------------------
NULL           pancake
Pizza          pasta
NULL           cookie
```

I have tried this SQL statement, but it's not returning the desired output:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN id % 2 = 0 
            THEN title 
    END AS left_title,
    CASE WHEN id %2 != 0 
            THEN title 
    END AS right_title
FROM
    recipes
```

Comment: I have t ried using LEAD, LAG and %2 with case statement but didn't work.

Comment: just did. That's one of the way I tried, I have tried different ways , using Lead, lag etc/

Comment: i guess the other thing is if you have 4 and 5 blank for whatever reason and 6 has a title, do you then would like to see 4 and 5 blank or not showing at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close.  You just need aggregation:

```
select max(case when id % 2 = 0 then title end) as left_title,
       max(case when id % 2 = 1 then title end) as right_title
from recipes
group by id / 2
order by min(id);
```

SQL Server does integer division, so `id / 2` is always an integer.

Comment: so if you have pages 4 and 5 are blank for whatever reason and there is a page 6 title how would this show?

Comment: You are missing order by id / 2

Comment: @AladejubeloOluwashina . . . I think I agree.  The OP does appear to want the results in a particular order as well as in a particular format.

Answer (score 1):

Using CTE.. this should be give you a good CTE overview

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
  pageno int,
  title varchar(30)
)

INSERT INTO @table
  VALUES (1, 'pancake')
  , (2, 'pizza')
  , (3, 'pasta')
  , (5, 'cookie')


;
WITH cte_pages
AS (  -- generate page numbers
SELECT
  0 n,
  MAX(pageno) maxpgno
FROM @table
UNION ALL
SELECT
  n + 1 n,
  maxpgno
FROM cte_pages
WHERE n <= maxpgno),
cte_left
AS (   --- even
SELECT
  n,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) rn
FROM cte_pages
WHERE n % 2 = 0),
cte_right
AS (   --- odd
SELECT
  n,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) rn
FROM cte_pages
WHERE n % 2 <> 0)
SELECT
  tl.title left_title,
  tr.title right_title    --- final output
FROM cte_left l
INNER JOIN cte_right r
  ON l.rn = r.rn
LEFT OUTER JOIN @table tl
  ON tl.pageno = l.n
LEFT OUTER JOIN @table tr
  ON tr.pageno = r.n
```